# I'm using Google Apps to make an API to listen a POST request from webhook and have issues to print data in the GoogleSheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi i'm new in Google Apps and i trying to make an API to listen a POST resquest from webhook provides by the website Hotmart.com (marktplace), and put the information about the sales in the Google Sheets. The API works fine, but when have many sales on Hotmart in a short period of time a "bug" happens, some data ends up being placed in the same row in the spreadsheet, rather to put in the row below.

I try many always to solve that but i cant figureout, here is my code :

```
function doPost(e) {
//DADOS PASSADOS COMO QUERYSTRING
//Procedimento do Webhook para poder utilizar o dados enviados da plataforma online (nesse 
caso a Hotmart).


//Abrindo a aba da planilha.
var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('12IvR9nw-8I-AfpcmBaeHraHNmbHiRzSzmfdctyVKR9I');
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dados Hotmart Brutos");
var lastRow = Math.max(sheet.getLastRow(),1);

//Verifica qual a ultima linha e insere uma depois.

//Infos compras produtos  
var myData = e.parameters;
var myData = JSON.stringify(myData)
var myData = JSON.parse(myData);


var id = myData.transaction;
var dataCompra = myData.purchase_date;
var dataAprovacao = myData.confirmation_purchase_date;
var nomeProduto = myData.prod_name;
var parcela = myData.recurrency;
var comissaoHotmart = myData.cms_marketplace;
var precoProduto = myData.price;
var precoMoeda = myData.currency;
var status = myData.status;
var tipoPagamento = myData.payment_type;
var meioPagamento = myData.payment_engine;
var parcelaPagamento = myData.productOfferPaymentMode
var emailComprador = myData.email;
var nomeComprador = myData.name;
var dddComprador = myData.phone_local_code;
var telefoneComprador = myData.phone_number;
var URLboleto = myData.billet_url;
var codigodeBarra = myData.billet_barcode;
var recusa = myData.refusal_reason; 
var nossaEntrada = precoProduto - comissaoHotmart - 2.49;

sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,2).setValue(id)
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,3).setValue(dataCompra)
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,4).setValue(dataAprovacao)
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,5).setValue(parcela)
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,6).setValue(comissaoHotmart)
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,7).setValue(precoProduto)
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,8).setValue(precoMoeda)
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,9).setValue(status)
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,10).setValue(tipoPagamento)
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,11).setValue(meioPagamento)
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,12).setValue(parcelaPagamento)
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,13).setValue(emailComprador)
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,14).setValue(nomeComprador)
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,15).setValue(dddComprador)
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,16).setValue(telefoneComprador)
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,17).setValue(URLboleto)
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,18).setValue(codigodeBarra)
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,19).setValue(recusa)
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,20).setValue(nossaEntrada)  



SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Some one can help me ?

PS : my postData.type is

Comment: Try LockService

Comment: How i have try ?

Comment: Thanks dude, you are almost a god !

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running into concurrency issues. In this case the [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock) will do the trick for you as it can prevent multiple processes from modifying a shared resource and avoid collisions.